# Not able to read the marathi pdf having CDAC_GISTSulekh font

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, pdfbox

I having a document which is build in the CDAC_GISTSulekh font. I am using pdfboclx 2.0 API to read the pdf file. There is no any error as such while parsing the document. But the o/p is not coming in proper marathi on eclipse console.
Any help at the earliest would appreciate.

Comment: Please share the PDF file. And check whether you can get the text with Adobe Reader.

Comment: @Tilman Yes i am getting text with adobe reader

Comment: After seeing the "answer" (which will soon be deleted because it isn't an answer) "showing पपरष in case of पुरुष" I wonder if this is a problem that similar to something I've heard about thai, i.e. characters having to be combined. If it is so, then I'm pessimistic. Nevertheless, it would be useful to have a link to the PDF.

Comment: This indeed reminds of issues similar to those discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15566820/1729265) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30804279/1729265). For an actual analysis please share the pdf in question.

Comment: @varpekv, Did you find any solution for your question. I am also facing same problem.

Comment: @Abhi Not yet doing more reasearch

Comment: @varpekv, Okay I will also do research on it.

Comment: @varpekv can you please share what did you do resolve this issue?? I am facing similar problem with similar PDF.. I struggling with the PDF reading part since many weeks but not able read pdf accurately .. any of your help i would highly appreciated.. please let me know your solution or findings

Comment: @Abhi did you resolve your issue related PDF reading .. facing similar problem with similar PDF not dont have any concrete solution please share your findings ..  I would be thankful to my fellow Puneity for any help in this matter.. :-)

Comment: @VirajNalawade, no. I am still researching for correct solution.

Comment: @Abhi thanks for the reply..  I have a partial solution which does ocr but it is not accurate.. if we are working on similar issue we can collaborate.. what you say?

Comment: @VirajNalawade, Yes, let me know how we can proceed further.

Comment: @ Abhi & @VirajNalawade we'll create chat room and discuss this issue over there. Please let me know your views on this?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea @varpekv ..

Comment: currently i dont know what can be done ahead but discussion will help @Abhi